# Proper real limestone veneer installation.?

Tags: installation, stone, veneer

I am having a company do stone veneer on my house. I’ve never done it myself and wanted a pro job done. I’m replacing the siding myself and have a pretty good understanding of carpentry skills when it comes to framing.

I had the house wrapped in tyvek over OSB already.

The stone guys installed the wire with was looks to be 1/2 staples over the tyvek. Then a scratch coat over that. Is that ok to do that? I would think they would need nails or at least 1 1/4 staples.

Is installing the mesh right over the tyvek ok or should there be a different barrier on top of the tyvek?

Finally, is installing veneer on OSB okay? I am now seeing that that isn’t good practice to do that.

I live in Ohio where we get 4 seasons and extreme high and low temperatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The stone guys installed the wire with was looks to be 1/2 staples over the tyvek. Then a scratch coat over that. Is that ok to do that?

Yes that is the normal way to install the wire mesh. If your OSB is only 1/2" thick then a longer staple will not hold much better unless you hit a stud. If there enough staples then the brick is not going anywhere.

> Finally, is installing veneer on OSB okay?

There is always a difference of opinion on anything on the Internet, but if you have house wrap under the veneer it is just like any other type of siding. If moisture gets behind it then it should be stopped by the house wrap. The top of the veneer should be protected from water by some type of cap to keep water from entering behind the brick.

If you hired a professional and you have seen their work you have to figure they know what they are doing if they have been in business for a while.

Good luck!